# While exchanging access_token --> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth

While exchanging access_token with google for user consent at GetResponse(), I am receiving this error

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

My code is:

```
                     var postData = "code=" + strCode;
            postData += "&" + "client_id=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"].ToString();
            postData += "&" + "client_secret=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecretKey"].ToString();
            postData += "&" + "redirect_uri=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"].ToString(); /*http://my-domain.com/GoogleOAuth/AccessToken*/
            postData += "&" + "grant_type=" + "authorization_code";

            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");

            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
            httpWebRequest.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "http://my-domain.com";

            using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            var httpResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            ViewBag.Result = Json(httpResponse);
            var responseFromAPI = "";
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseFromAPI = streamReader.ReadToEnd();                  
            }
```

I tried checking my request in, request bin and it looks correct to me as per https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#server-flow
here is a screenshot of my request

[request for access token.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNUAi.png)

It would be of great help, if anyone can tell me where am i going wrong.

Is there a way to verify my authorization code, because for some reason I feel might be there is a problem with my authorization code.

Do let me know if any more detail is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you are doing this manually and not using Googles client library?

Answer (score 0):

I cant see how you are applying the post values to the body

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

They must be in the above format one long html request string.  Your content type looks correct.

Comment: you are forgetting code.  authorization_code exchange requires that you send the code.  this might help https://www.daimto.com/google-apis-auth-simple/

Comment: I am not sure about my redirect url format. can you take a look over it.

Comment: I dont think you need the / on the end and it has to be one that you added in Google developer console.